# How to express giving two people some privacy?

Tags: phrase-request

Recently I noticed that a young girl waited for several hours, so as to be able to pass the break with my younger colleague. So my friend and I took a walk outside.

Though this is not something I expect to have to explain, I still wondered how to politely express it. Obviously I don’t mean they had anything improper in mind. But they could talk without everyone listening.

Would 尊重兩人隱私 sound improper? What are polite expressions?

Comment: 让他们讨论自己的事情，我们最好别管闲事吧！

Answer (score 4):

"Give them some privacy" = "給他們一點私人空間吧"

私人空間 means "private space", To give a person some private space means to leave him alone for a while.

Answer (score 4):

你（你们）能回避一下吗？or
你（你们）方便回避一下吗？more politely asking.
If you meant they want to have some privacy and can nicely ask others to leave.

Answer (score 3):

If I get your gist correctly, 3 people are waiting, then a boy arrives, who the girl really wants to see. You say to the other person or persons present:

Let's go outside so they can talk in private.
我们到外面去，让他们单独谈谈。

Answer (score 3):

How about a less direct translation:

不要在那儿当电灯泡。

which roughly translates to something like: don't be a third-wheel over there.

Comment: exact translation in bkrs: 电灯泡 2) slang unwanted third party accompanying courting couple; chaperone

Comment: A Chinese-English Dict also gives third-wheel, like I wrote above, for their definition.